# Extracting and replacing dates in different formats

Tags: powershell

I have been tasked with cleaning up the names of some files before. Most of them are stamped with some kind of date, below you can see some of the output I get when looping through most of the likely suspects for renaming:
[image]
My problem is that my users have been fairly inconsistent in their naming-schemes - while most of the documents have a date stamp, there is no consistent pattern, I have, for instance:

- dd.mm.yy
- dd.mm.yyyy
- dd_mm_yy
- dd <monthname> yyyy
- etc.

I want to extract all of these dates, and add them to the front of each filename in the format yyyy.mm.dd.

Googling seems to suggest that I should use one of the parsing cmdlets, but I am having a hard time figuring out the specifics for one of the cases mentioned above, much less figuring out how I can handle all of them.

Some input on what may be fruitful approaches would be much appreciated!

Comment: Powershell can [parse about any](http://dusan.kuzmanovic.net/2012/05/07/powershell-parsing-date-and-time/) date format, as long as they are consistent. Instead of a catch-all solution, try to aim for the lowest-hanging fruits. Achieve easy victories by converting the simple cases in batch and the most complex via hand. For example, the meeting of 24 November is not worth the effort - what's the year?